# Unable fetch and show data using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying show user's name ,Email ID but Show '1' as output everytime.
Where ever I am trying to fetch and Show the value,It's only Showing 1 as output.

Database :

```
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<?php
require_once('config/config.php');
//Counting Member
$members = "SELECT count( * ) as  id FROM admin";
$member_result = $mysqli->query($members);
$total_member = mysqli_num_rows($member_result);
//Showing Admin Name
$admin_name = "SELECT `name` FROM `admin` WHERE id='1'";
$name_result = $mysqli->query($admin_name);
$name_sh = mysqli_num_rows($name_result);
//Showing Email
$admin_email = "SELECT `email` FROM `admin` WHERE id='1'";
$email_result = $mysqli->query($admin_email);
$email_sh = mysqli_num_rows($email_result);
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test1');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($mysqli === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

HTML Code :

```
                                    <div class="account-dropdown js-dropdown">
                                        <div class="info clearfix">
                                            <div class="image">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <img src="images/icon/avatar-01.jpg" alt="John" />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="content">
                                                <h5 class="name">
                                                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name_sh; ?></a>
                                                </h5>
                                                <span class="email"><?php echo $email_sh; ?></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

It's only displaying 1 instead of value.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` will return number of `rows` , and you are assigning this to your variable `$name_sh` and `$email_sh` , thats why it is showing integer value

Comment: There's no need to enclose integer literals in single quotes in SQL. That's for string literals.

Comment: You can fetch both of the values in 1 select.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are displaying the result of `mysqli_num_rows`, which returns the number of rows in the result (and which is therefore always equal to 1).

Use instead [`mysqli_stmt_fetch`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_stmt_fetch) to fetch the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$admin_name = "SELECT `name` FROM `admin` WHERE id='1'";
$name_result = $mysqli->query($admin_name);
$result=mysqli->fetch_array($name_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```